# 419 Page Expired error for particularly any POST request, After the website has been hosted on a live server. (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

After hosting my website on a live server, I started getting a new error that wasn't there before "419|Page Expired" on any POST request i.e. (Login, Register, Search). I looked everywhere for a solution to my problem and in most cases everyone said that the problem was because of the (csrf) tokens, however,
{{ csrf_field() }} is present in all my forms and in meta. Listed below are all the methods that I have tried to solve this problem so we could eliminate them:

1. Change {{ csrf_field() }} to @csrf.
2. Clear Cache.
3. Change Permissions to 755.
4. Modify my config/session.php file.
5. Generate a new Key for the application.
6. Change (Session drivers) in .env to "database" and "cookie" instead of "file".
7. Finally, the method that had quite an impact but of course I can't use that method, was when I added '*' in the protected Except [] array, The search field worked like a charm and showed the results, however, Login kept re-directing back to the home page and not actually logging in.

I hope someone finds a solution to my problem.